# JS Фокусировка и ввод текста в `input`

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование, html-form

Представляю HTML код формы: https://pastebin.com/ZEEE36x4

Следующий скрипт, который я выполняю на странице (сайт принадлежит не мне) призван ввести определённые данные в поле ввода на форме:

```
var inp = document.querySelector('[data-marker="registration-form/input"]');
inp.select();
inp.focus();
inp.value = '79000000000';
```

Проблема заключается в том, что при нажатии кнопки для продолжения (кнопка с надписью "Продолжить" на форме) происходит сброс установленного значения `input.value`. Вызов `select()`, `focus()`, `click()` вообще ничего не делают, хотя должны активировать поле ввода. Если делать вручную, то всё работает. Не понимаю как активировать ввод в этом поле. Есть идеи?

Comment: "при нажатии кнопки для продолжения" - ??

Comment: @Igor Кнопка для отправки номера и загрузки следующей страницы - логично же из текста на кнопке.

Comment: Что "логично же"? Я понятия не имею, что означает "нажатие кнопки для продолжения". Впрочем, можете не объяснять, а подождать других телепатов.

Comment: @Igor На кнопке написано "Продолжить", поэтому я использовал такой оборот.

Comment: @Igor Впрочем это даже к делу по сути не относится. Проблема же в том, что курсор на ввод в поле не ставится.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я разобрался в чём была проблема. Значения хранятся в некоторой модели во время выполнения JavaScript и отображаются в форме. Обновление значения поля не приведет к обновлению модели, поскольку обновления привязаны к входным событиям. Таким образом, чтобы заполнить форму и "по настоящему" изменить `input.value` нужно выполнить:

```
var event = new Event('input', {
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true,
});

inp.dispatchEvent(event);

const pasteEvent = Object.assign(new Event('paste', { bubbles: true, cancelable: true }), {
            clipboardData: {
                getData: (type = pasteType) => VALUE,
            },
        });
inp.dispatchEvent(pasteEvent);
```